# Postfix Spamassassin deferred queue massive error

Tags: postfix, centos6, dovecot, spamassassin

I have been witnessing some massive problems with my Postfix email server, equipped with Dovecot, and spamassassin.

The log files show errors like below, and there are thousands of such lines in the logs.

```
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<alozano1@terra.es>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<aloupie@thetis.gr>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<alozanop@visteon.com>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<alowe@wset.com>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<alove@wtamu.edu>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: warning: 5ABBA1425BF: defer service failure
Mar 13 14:21:48 centos postfix/qmgr[1908]: 5ABBA1425BF: to=<alouisjr12_10@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=1929, delays=1706/223/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

This is creating massive trouble with the email servers, as it is preventing me from sending any emails.

***UPDATE***
I managed to overcome the POstfix logs shown above by deleting the complete queue using `postsuper -d ALL`

But, now i need to overcome the issue with Spamassassin not getting connected.

```
Mar 13 15:09:49 centos spamc[2511]: connect to spamd on 127.0.0.1 failed, retrying (#2 of 3): Connection refused
Mar 13 15:09:50 centos spamc[2511]: connect to spamd on 127.0.0.1 failed, retrying (#3 of 3): Connection refused
Mar 13 15:09:51 centos spamc[2511]: connection attempt to spamd aborted after 3 retries
```

Any help with this is much appreciated, thanks in advance, let me know if you need anything and i will upload it for you to see

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue thus far?

Comment: 1--I deleted the deffered queue using `postsuper -d ALL deferred`
2--I tried blocking the IP address that was creating these problemd
3--I changed my networks field in main.cf to only include localhost and the 192.168.0.0/16 private subnet

Comment: The main issue i saw was, someone trying to authenticate using my ID, and I have changed my passwords since then. Also, i have been trying to use spamassassin to help overcome this, flushing the queue `postqueue -f` doesnt help

Comment: when using `postsuper -r ALL` i get almost 1100 messages which are queued, we never sent so many messages.

Comment: Seems to overcome those messages in my Log file after i deleted the complete queue using `postsuper -d ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These following steps seems to have fixed the issue with postfix.

1. Changed my password.
2. Deleted postfix queue using `postsuper -d ALL`
3. Restart spamassassin to resolve the connection to spamd issue.

Comment: So what's the reason under the hood?

Comment: Basic hacking attempt using brute force, which was successful. Normal procedure to mitigate such actions were used.